# Wiriting a multidimensional numpy array into a CSV file

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have a 2D array which I want to write into a csv file. I am using the following code to do it. My array is already a *float32 dtype* array. Then I'm converting the array into a numpy using `.asarray()` function. Now i want to write it to a csv file and using the following code:

```
activaiton_array = np.asarray(activation_list)
np.savetxt("/home/workstation/activation_data_file_1.csv", activaiton_array,fmt='%f', delimiter=",",)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
np.savetxt("/home/workstation/activation_data_file_1.csv", activaiton_array,fmt='%f', delimiter=",",)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1073, in savetxt
fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))

TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: I'm guessing that it doesn't work for 3+D arrays, and that it doesn't 'unpack' enough layers to get to the float, so it's left with an array and is stuck. How many dimensions do you have?

Comment: please give an example of the specific array that you want to write to csv

Comment: sorry i didn't specify that it is actually a 2d array. i will edit the post.

Comment: Your code works fine with a 2D array like this: `x=np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=float); np.savetxt('test.csv', x, fmt='%f', delimiter=',')`. Can you give an example of an array that gives you an error?

Comment: array([[ -47.44044876,   53.48169327,  -75.20567322, -251.82580566,
         -16.14718628,   14.18919754,   -7.94054556,   61.17417145,
          90.40328217,  -39.49287796, -169.89468384,  180.6479187 ,
          14.25799465,  -40.71538162,  129.78521729,   78.43473053,
         -20.75302696,  -51.29152679,   -2.59940243,   27.26807022,
        -115.14477539,   66.79769135,   14.48125744, -170.70048523,
          68.43611145,  -90.43571472, -190.86634827,   17.81785965,
         -56.12176514,    7.12983942]], dtype=float32)]

Comment: This is a part of the array cause its a much bigger array.

Answer (score 0):

If `activaiton_array` is a 2d array of floats then `savetxt` iterates over rows (the first dimension) and performs

```
fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
```

This expects `row` to be a 1d array of floats; `format` is derived from your `fmt` specification.  In effect it is doing

```
'%f, %f, %f'%(1.23, 23.23, 1.0)
```

The error means that `row` is not 1d or that its elements are not numbers.

I'd have to run a few tests to see whether `TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray` is produced by `row` being 2d (i.e. your array is really 3d), or by `row` being an dtype array containing arrays.

You need to show us `activaiton_array.dtype` and `activaiton_array.shape`.

Comment: Thank you for your approach and I have solved the problem and now i can write it in an Excel file. I just had to reshape the numpy array after converting it into a numpy array. BTW the array dtype is float32 and shape is (num_of_iteration x 1x150).

Comment: That middle `1` dimension would create problems without being obvious.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
np.savetxt("/home/workstation/activation_data_file_1.csv",activaiton_array.flatten())
```

Comment: This seems to be working and i can write without getting the error. But all the data are being written in a single column. But i want a specific number lets say 150  in a single row and the next 150 in the next row. actually i wanna say is i want to write the 2d array as a 2d array in the CSV file which is not what i am getting.

Comment: Ok, I see. Maybe you could use `np.array2string(activaiton_array, separator=', ')`  -> [[1,2,3,...],[1,2,3,...]] ?